# 0-1 Knapsack - other input values doesn't work on program

Tags: java, output, knapsack-problem

What I need to do is to implement the 0-1 Knapsack problem. There is an input file named "In0302.txt" and an output file named "Out0302.txt". The program gets values from INPUT file and saves the results to OUTPUT file. I got my input values on paper from my "dr". 
Putting them to the file seems to be ok in OUTPUT file. But... on classes "dr" tried to put other values  in INPUT file, but the program didn't work. What is more there was no even an error, but the program was still compiling and compiling... and I can't get know where the problem is. Does anybody would try to change something in this code or tell me what is wrong ?

```
INPUT:
4 6
2 1
3 2
3 4
4 5

OUTPUT:
1 4
2 3
```

JAVA CODE:

```
public class Knapsack {
  public static int max(int a, int b){
    if (a > b){
      return a;
    }
    else{
      return b;
    }  
  }
  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int n = 0, W = 0, p[] = null, w[] = null, S[][] = null, S_object[][] = null;
    //s[][] = arrays with values

    try {
      FileReader fr = new FileReader("In0302.txt");
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
      String line = in.readLine();
      String[] cols = line.split(" ");

      n = Integer.parseInt(cols[0]); W = Integer.parseInt(cols[1]); 

      p = new int[n+1]; w = new int[n+1];

      int k = 1;

      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        cols = line.split(" ");
        p[k] = Integer.parseInt(cols[0]);
        w[k] = Integer.parseInt(cols[1]);
        k++;
      }

      S = new int[W+1][n+1];
      S_object = new int[W+1][n+1];

      for(int weight = 0; weight <= W; weight++){
        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
          if (i == 0){
            S[weight][i] = 0;
            S_object[weight][i] = 0;
          }
          else if (weight < w[i]){
            S[weight][i] = S[weight][i-1];
            S_object[weight][i] = S_object[weight][i-1];
          }
          else if (weight >= w[i-1]){
            S[weight][i]=max(S[weight][i-1],S[weight-w[i]][i-1]+p[i]);

            if ((max(S[weight][i-1], S[weight-w[i]][i-1] + p[i]) == (S[weight-w[i]][i-1] + p[i])))       {
              S_object[weight][i]=i;
            } //added new element to bag
            else {
              S_object[weight][i]=S_object[weight][i-1];
            } //nothing has been added
          }  
        }
      }
      in.close();
      fr.close(); 
    }

    catch (IOException e){
      System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
    }   

    File outputFile;
    FileWriter out;

    try{
      outputFile = new File("Out0302.txt");
      out = new FileWriter(outputFile);
      String line = "";

      int max_value = S[W][n];
      for (int m = n; m > 0; m--){
        if (S[W][m] == max_value){
          line = " " + S_object[W][m] + "";
          int temp = W;

          while ((temp-w[S_object[temp][m]]) > 0){
            temp = temp - w[S_object[temp][m]];
            line += " " + S_object[temp][m];
          }
          out.write(line + "\n");
          out.write("\n\t");
        }
      } 

      out.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("Arrar of values:");
    for(int weight = 0; weight <= W; weight++){
      for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        System.out.print(S[weight][i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println(""); 
    }

    System.out.println("Array of objects:");
    for(int weight = 0; weight <= W; weight++){
      for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        System.out.print(S_object[weight][i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: "the program was still compiling and compiling" -- I think you meant computing/calculating? Please use a debugger and give us at least a clue where it might go wrong.

Comment: I'm not such a good programmer like you. I'm using NetBeans and using debugger is not showing error. Maybe I do something wrong. Please try to change the values in INPUT file and maybe you'll find out what is wrong ;/

Comment: When I got you right, you don't have the input values that causes the weird behaviour. So the first thing to do is: get them, or produce them yourself. The next step is to run the program with the debugger to figure out what is happening - it won't show you an error with a blinking arrow, but goes through the program step by step as in execution. There must be an infinite loop somewhere, under certain conditions.

Comment: You can put the values you want, just different than those in INPUT file are given.